# Cannot delete entity with child entities

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, breeze

Having problems deleting a record that has associate records.

It's a really simple setup: A "component" can have one or more (or none!) "componentProcesses".  If I delete a component that has no processes, there are no errors and the component is successfully deleted from the database.  If I delete a component WITH processes then I get the following message on calling manager.saveChanges():

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.componentProcesses_dbo.components_ComponentID". The conflict occurred in database "mydb", table "dbo.components", column 'Id'
```

The model is basically:

```
Public Class component
    Public Property Id() As Integer

    ...irrelevant fields removed....

    Public Overridable Property Processes() As ICollection(Of componentProcess)        
End Class

Public Class componentProcess
    Public Property Id() As Integer

    ...irrelevant fields removed....

    Public Property ComponentID() As Integer 'process belongs to component
    Public Property ProcessId() As Integer 'links to specific process

    Public Overridable Property Component() As component
    Public Overridable Property Process() As process
End Class
```

I won't show the "component" and "process" models as they're just simple id-based static tables.

When a user deletes a component, the code is:

```
    //editComponent is a ko.observable containing currently-being-edited component

    //editComponent().processes().forEach(function (p) {
    //    p.entityAspect.setDeleted(); //sets to deleted but won't persist if save isn't called
        //editComponent().processes.remove(function (_process) {
        //    return _process.id() == p.id()
        //});
    //});

    editComponent().entityAspect.setDeleted(); //sets to deleted but won't persist if save isn't called
    editComponent(null); //empty observable to trigger screen UI updates
```

As you can see from the above code, I've been experimenting with commenting out various lines to see if it affects the outcome, but it doesn't. Regardless of whether I set each child "componentProcess" entityaspect to "deleted" or not, I get the same error on saving changes.

Cascadedelete is on for this relationship and if I delete a component in SQL enterprise manager, all child componentprocesses are immediately deleted so that works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL error seems inconsistent with your claim that the db relationship is set up for cascade delete ... although I can't explain how you get away with it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Maybe you can trace the sequence of database calls?

I do know what's troubling your attempt to delete the child processes: you're changing the `editComponent.processes` array while you're iterating over it!  That's a no-no.

Every time you call `setDeleted`, Breeze removes that `Process` entity from the parent`editComponent.processes` array. When the iterator loops back around, it's skipping the next `process`.

You need to **make a copy of the array** before calling `setDeleted` on its contents. Something like this should do it:

```
// copy with slice()
var processes = editComponent().processes().slice(); 
// iterate over the copy
processes.forEach(function (p) {
    // Breeze removes each `p` from its parent editComponent.processes array
    p.entityAspect.setDeleted(); //marks deleted but won't persist until saveChanges is called
});

expect(editComponent().processes().length).to.equal(0);
```

HTH

Comment: Forgot about this as I got distracted. Was just testing app and fell over this error and remembered I'd asked the question. The sample code worked perfectly. Thanks again Ward, I understand what you mean now.